# I am getting TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float for this code

Tags: python

```
a=100
count=0
b=105
for i in range(a,b+1):
    visited=[0 for i in range(0,10)]
    num=i
    while(num):
        x=num%10
        if (visited[x]):
            break
        visited[num%10]=1
        num=num/10
    if num==0:
        count+=1
if count==0:
    print("No unique number")
else:
    print(count)
```

'''unique number refers to no two identical digits in a number'''
I tried implementing this code but I kept getting type error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to  add a comment in the code where you get the error, and copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question.

Comment: when you do `num/10`, the result is a float. Perhaps you mean `num // 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Well this can be done as an one-liner if you use a `list comprehension`.

The `num for num in range(100, 106)` part generates all integers from `100` to `105`, while the `if` check if all digits of `num` appear at most `1` time, this is done after constructing a `list` of digits from the string representation of `num`, which are counted using the `Counter` from the `collections` module.

```
from collections import Counter
count = [num for num in range(100, 106) if all(x <= 1 for x in Counter(list(str(num))).values())]
print(count)
```

Output:

```
[102, 103, 104, 105]
```

Comment: @Yami Shetty Take a look at my answer, see if it works for you.